# How to get old Mapping and Voronoi nodes into Blender 2.82?

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, vector-mapping

I noticed that some nodes changed significantly with Blender 2.81 and 2.82.
Now I can't follow older tutorials, because some have different options than me.

- Voronoi Node is totally different
- Mapping Node is missing it's maximum / minimum clipping controls

**Q:** How to get these older nodes back into Blender 2.82?

[image][image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good news. Blender will automatically convert these old nodes for you.
Just get an older Blender version and copy/paste them.

1. Download [Blender 2.80](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.80/) and create your material.
2. Make sure the nodes **are connected** (or it won't work).
3. Copy/paste an object with the material into Blender 2.82, the nodes will be converted.

[image: animation 1]

Oops! The *(Math) Substract* node is not shown in the animation. Here it is: [image: voronoi intensity crackle]

[image: animation 2]