# How do I replicate the 'Chebychev Crackle' with the new Voronoi node?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, procedural

I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9iO-7RbDSw8.

After 2.81 the voronoi texture node has changed and I cannot replicate the same **Chebychev Crackle effect** with the new node.

[image]

In the new node -
It looks like the voronoi color output is the right one but it has no height data to manipulate the wave texture.

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Blender can convert it automatically: [How to get old Mapping and Voronoi nodes into Blender 2.82?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/179349/78972)

Comment: Interesting! But I must say it is close, but not exactly the same. that will do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: use this construction to replicate the old node]

This construction replicates the old node.